# regular expression no hits in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression

```
(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)
```

which is supposed to find anything between `<TEXT>` and `</TEXT>`.

I paste my string on http://pythex.org/ and it does work, but the following implementation in python does not find anything

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)', text)
```

where `text` contains what I pasted into the window there (used the debugger, pasted output of variable). Do I need to pay attention to something special?

*Some additional output*

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)")
>>> print(pattern)
re.compile('(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)')
>>> re.DOTALL
16
>>> pattern.findall(text)
[]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even work. `enc` is an invalid argument for `open` and it seems that `file` is a filename.

Comment: How do you output your result? The regex seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the file content?

Comment: Maybe there are linebreaks between the opening and closing tags? Did you expect `re.DOTALL` to globally activate dotall-mode? You have to [pass the flag to the function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).

Comment: @tobias_k that was it!

Answer (score 0):

I get the "correct" output with

```
re.findall(r'(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

I assumed the default value in `re` to be the same with pythex, which it apparently is not.

Comment: Dropping the ? after the .* changes the behaviour to greedily include everything from the first <TEXT> to the last </TEXT>.  That said, it works for me with `re.findall(r'(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)', text, re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really ought to be considering a token parser rather than regular expressions - is this an xml or html input?  In that case, the you might want to consider this question & the top answer here: [How Do I Parse XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)